# Mongoose where count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Assuming I have this mongoose query:

```
const actors = await Actor.aggregate([{ 
    "$group": {_id: "$loc.coordinates", count:{$sum:1}}  
}])
```

Is there a way to get only the `actors` that have a `count > 1` ?

Comment: For `actors` or for group field(`$loc.coordinates`) ?

Comment: Oops, sorry: the group field `$loc.coordinates`

Comment: You can use `$match` stage after `$group`... `{ $match: { count: { $gt: 1 }} }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thank you! Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage after [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
const actors = await Actor.aggregate([
   { "$group": { "_id": "$loc.coordinates", "count": { "$sum": 1 }} },
   { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 }} }  
])
```